# Keystrokes not registering in Python/Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am new to Python and especially new to Pygame. Been working on a basic space invader type game to attempt to learn more about Pygame, but I cannot figure out the code for moving the user ship. Have looked up some tutorials on it, and I THINK my code looks good, but I might be looking over something. I am in Python version 3.8 and Pygame version 1.9.6.

```
'''
This script is creating a space invader type game with the Pygame module.

Tutorial following YT video from  freecodecamp.org
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfWpgLFMI7w&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org)
'''

import sys
import pygame

# Initializing Pygame
# (ALWAYS REQUIRED)
pygame.init()

# Screen Dimensions
width = 800
height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# Other Game Settings
framerate = pygame.time.Clock()
framerate.tick(60)

# Setting Title and Images
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Invaders')
icon = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
player_ship =  pygame.image.load('space-invaders.png')

def player(x,y):
    '''
    Draws the player's ship on the screen at (x,y) coordinates.
    '''
    screen.blit(player_ship,(x, y))

# Game Function
def game():
    '''
    Actual code for the game itself.
    '''
    # Sets the starting position for the player's ship
    playerX = 368 # Middle of Screen (on x-axis)
    playerY = 506 # 30px off bottom of the screen (y-axis)

    x_change = 0

    # Game Loop
    game_exit = False
    while not game_exit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_exit = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    game_exit = True
                elif event.type == pygame.K_d:
                    x_change = 5
                elif event.type == pygame.K_a:
                    x_change = -5
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    x_change = 0

            playerX += x_change

            print(x_change) # Using this to see if the script is recognizing the user keystrokes

        # Setting Screen RGB
        screen.fill((0,0,0))

        player(playerX, playerY)

        # Screen Update
        # (ALWAYS REQUIRED)
        pygame.display.update()

game()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The game will open up and display the black background with the user ship image like I want it to, but then when I use the 'A' or 'D' keys to move the ship side to side, it remains in place and prints out an x_change value of 0 as if I am not pressing keys. I have tried swapping 'A' and 'D' out for different letter keys as well as arrow keys, but it doesn't change anything, making me believe it is just an issue with the code itself rather than the specific keys I am using to control the ship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you're checking for an `event.type` of `pygame.K_d`, etc.

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_exit = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE:      # <-- HERE
                game_exit = True
            elif event.type == pygame.K_d:         # <-- HERE
                x_change = 5
            elif event.type == pygame.K_a:         # <-- AND HERE
                x_change = -5
```

The `event.type` cannot be equal to *both* `pygame.KEYDOWN` and `pygame.K_d` at the same time!.  If you check the [documentation on event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html), notice that the key-code is sent in `event.key`, so it's a simple fix.

> KEYDOWN           key, mod, unicode, scancode
> KEYUP             key, mod

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_exit = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:      # <-- FIX HERE
                game_exit = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:         # <-- FIX HERE
                x_change = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:         # <-- AND FIX HERE
                x_change = -5
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it had to be something that flew over my head like that. I had just assumed I had the actual condition correct already and it was an issue with something else. I need to make sure I check everything next time. You are a lifesaver!